# access webservice as odbc layer?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

we are looking at leveraging existing web services as a data source in BOXI universe. wondering if its easy to expose the web service as odbc ( that can be easily used as a connection in BOXI universe) ?

Comment: "Expose as ODBC" means "write an ODBC provider", so, "no".

Comment: Something exactly like an ODBC provider.